# Падает Access при сортировки

Tags: ms-access

Доброго времени суток. Есть база. К ней существует вложенный запрос. 
Создаю запрос на выборку записей. Делаю сортировку, и при выполнении Access вылетает.

```
SELECT Emitent_short_name, Format(date_location,'Short Date'), Format(date_repayment,'Short Date'), iif(summa_location=0,0,Format(summa_location,'### ### ###')),  iif(clear_procent=0,0,Format(clear_procent,'### ### ###')), iif(dohod_nalog=0,'0',CSTR(Round(dohod_nalog*100,2))+'%'), iif(procent=0,0,Format(procent,'### ### ###'))  From Q_veksel where investor_short_name like 'ир' AND((date_location<CDATE('31.07.2017')) And (date_repayment>CDATE('31.08.2017'))) order by Emitent_short_name
```

Если выполнять без сортировки то все работает.

Comment: А как именно выполняется запрос (прямое открытие, как источник данных, VBA-код), что означает термин "вылетает", и какое выдаётся сообщение об ошибке, нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: 1) как источник данных. 2) Термин вылетает значит то что программа крашится.(умирает процесс, закрывается). Сообщения нет. Просто стандартное окно windows о том что Программа перезагружается.

Comment: Выполняется ли этот же запрос из конструктора, или тоже обрушивает среду исполнения? Падает ли среда, если запрос создать как статический, и указывать в качестве источника данных именно его? Что пишется в системный лог и отчёт ОС об ошибке (который она хочет отослать в M$) при падении приложения? Сколько записей и из скольких записей отбирает запрос? Каков в Мбайтах размер файла БД?

Comment: В конструкторе тоже самое. Проблему решил уже, отсортировал в коде. Спасибо за то что отозвался.